# Problem of activities

Tags: java, android

My game consists of a player that hopes between ropes.
For now, I created the player and the rope classes.
 Each one contains details about the object and its movement patterns.
What is the next step in orfer to link between them?
  Iwant the player to stick on a rope once they have the same x.
Should i create an activitt Game that implements this attach method?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you asking if you should add an empty object attached to the rope which the player attach to when he has the same x ?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of your previous question posted a few hours prior. If you'd like to refine how you're explaining the question, please use the edit link, rather than repeating the topic in a separate post. Duplicates tend to split useful information between multiple pages, making it harder for users to find the best answers in one place. So we tend to favour having a single canonical question post for each topic.